# Gojs state persist even after clearing instance

Tags: javascript, gojs

Initialising state with

```
        const divElement: HTMLDivElement = document.getElementById(
            'fpApp'
        ) as HTMLDivElement;
        const fp: Floorplan = new Floorplan(divElement);
```

clearing state on new floor switch with with

```
fp.clear()
```

but still previous state is somewhere persisted in gojs Json.
It was working till few days back but started breaking all of a sudden

does not allow to create new diagram

Answer (score 2):

First, have you been using https://gojs.net/latest/projects/floorplanner/FloorPlanner.html or the TypeScript version (https://gojs.net/latest/projects/floorplannerTS/index.html)?

If you are using the TypeScript version, it appears there is a bug involving the storage library it depends on, which will be fixed in the next release.

If you are using the other version, I'll need more information, since I'm not seeing the same problem you are. How exactly can I reproduce your problem?

Comment: I am using TypeScript version. reinitializing the floorplan instance with div on every new floor worked instead of just fp.clear()

Comment: Just found out,they fixed this bug with new version